# Concatenating Data from Two Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following data. Anywhere FirstName is blank I'd like to combine that Note data to the end of the Note of the previous line. The example is how the data appears in the table with no sorting. Is there a way to accomplish the result table through SQL? Thanks for any help!

```
FirstName   LastName   Note
---------   -------    --------------------------------------
John        Doe        likes bananas
Steve       Weiss      likes tomatoes and
                       also likes potatoes
John        Weiss      likes apples
Jeff        Marki      likes hotdogs
                       and also likes hambugers
Jenny       Boper      likes peaches
```

Expected Result

```
FirstName   LastName   Note
---------   -------    --------------------------------------
John        Doe        likes bananas
Steve       Weiss      likes tomatoes and also likes potatoes                           
John        Weiss      likes apples
Jeff        Marki      likes hotdogs and also likes hamburgers
Jenny       Boper      likes peaches
```

Comment: this is not how you store data in a database. With no ordering, next row is arbitrary and you *can not* get the result you are looking for. i see no point in posting the same question again as you asked it an hour or two ago.

Comment: @vkp The question I asked an hour ago resulted in a lot of confused people not actually answering my question so I decided to delete it and re-make it to make it more clear. Is there a better way of handling the process of asking a question that results in confusion beyond what I did? Thanks for the answer regardless, if it's not possible to achieve what I'm going for that's exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: This would be easy IF there is a row sequence, i.e. an identity field

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @YourTable table (FirstName varchar(50),LastName varchar(50),Note varchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('John','Doe','likes bananas'),
('Steve','Weiss','likes tomatoes and'),
(''     ,'','also likes potatoes'),
('John','Weiss','likes apples'),
('Jeff','Marki','likes hotdogs'),
(''    ,'','and also likes hambugers'),
('Jenny','Boper','likes peaches')

Select FirstName
      ,LastName
      ,Note     = FullText
From  (
        Select *
              ,FullText = Note+IIF(Lead(FirstName,1) over (Order By (Select null))='',' '+Lead(Note,1) over (Order By (Select Null)),'') 
         From @YourTable
      ) A
Where FirstName <>''
```

Returns

```
FirstName   LastName    Note
John        Doe         likes bananas
Steve       Weiss       likes tomatoes and also likes potatoes
John        Weiss       likes apples
Jeff        Marki       likes hotdogs and also likes hambugers
Jenny       Boper       likes peaches
```

> **Please Note:**

Where I have Order By (Select null)), you should really have a proper sequence number i.e. an identity field

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
DECLARE @TEMP_DATA TABLE
    (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    FIRSTNAME NVARCHAR(50),
    LASTNAME NVARCHAR(50),
    NOTE NVARCHAR(50)
    )

DECLARE @NO_NAME TABLE
    (
    IDEMPTY INT,
    EMPTYNAME NVARCHAR(50),
    EMTPYNAME NVARCHAR(50),
    NOTE2 NVARCHAR(50)
    )

INSERT  INTO @TEMP_DATA
SELECT  *
FROM    DATA

INSERT  INTO @NO_NAME
SELECT  *
FROM    @TEMP_DATA
WHERE   FIRSTNAME=''

UPDATE  @TEMP_DATA
SET     NOTE=NOTE+' '+NOTE2
FROM    @NO_NAME N
WHERE   ID=IDEMPTY-1

SELECT  FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,NOTE FROM @TEMP_DATA WHERE NOT FIRSTNAME LIKE ''
```